# Usage of the word "receptor"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In my understanding, the word "RECEPTOR" is used for only physiological things. Can you use the word for other categories, such as mechanical devices like "transceiver is a device that combines transmitter and receptor"?

Comment: It's unusual and the dictionary would not support it. However there might be a discipline of science or technology out that there that has adapted the term. In general it does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

*Transceiver* is a device that combines a transmitter and a *receiver*. However, the mechanical equivalent of *receptor* would be ***sensor*** or ***detector***.